# LLVM ir ll code compiled with debug - how to get line numbers

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

Compiled LLVM IR code with -O0 -g -emit-llvm -S

How can I pinpoint llvm block to C code?

Found a problematic code using Static Analysis of LL file, but need to know where this is in C code, without debugging it in the "head".

With C code and gdb this is easy, but how to use it with Clang/LLVM ll/bc setup.

Which tools I can use?

Comment: https://llvm.org/docs/SourceLevelDebugging.html

Comment: Thanks @Andrea Also found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29811763/get-precise-line-column-debug-info-from-llvm-ir so how do I get this info? Do I have to write some code and link against llvm or use some tool to? The doc and SO answer mention some functions/methods, but dont describe how to use then

Comment: If you want to get the data programmatically you can use the LLVM libraries. But the data is already there in the text IR, if you just want to find it with a text editor or `grep`. Look for `DILocation`.